# How to enforce a WiFi Broadcast Receiver to run onReceive at least once a day even though WiFi is all the time

Tags: android

In my app I have a WiFi broadcast receiver that fires off some actions if WiFi network is available.

The problem is, I have to fire off those actions at least once a day, and lets say the user is constantly under WiFi network, the onReceive method will never be called.

So how can I ensure that what happens there will happen at least once a day?

```
public class WiFiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        Log.d("asd", "WIFI");
        // DO THE THING
    } else {
        Log.d("asd", "NO WIFI");
    }
} // End of onReceive
```

In manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.WiFiReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I dont want to go as far as creating alarms that can trigger those actions daily.

Comment: So you want an alarm without using alarms? But alarm manager is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: ok will do this if no other way is possible

Answer (score 1):

One idea i would think of is register the BroadcastReceiver for more than just CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE event for example battery related events which practically are fired every day and make sure to execute whatever u need to on onReceive() method.

Comment: thats clever. can you give me an example of such event?

Comment: well there is ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED that indicates the level of the battery. but it needs to be registered explicitly from java code as it is a sticky broadcast. i would also pay attention on ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY, ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED

Comment: will strongly consider this :)

Comment: But even this might not occure every day: device on power supply for several days or big battery in low power mode.

Comment: of course but practically ive never heard of any mobile device which stays on power supply for several days, then it wouldnt be much "mobile" would it :D? havent heard of any device that can have that big battery so it wouldnt trigger an ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGE event

Comment: I think im gonna go with the alarm manager, as much as I'd not like it.